# How to align text on a sloping line?

Tags: html, css, shapes

Even the example code does not have: because it never occurs how to do:
[image]

How to implement, so that text is wrapped such that it forms a shape?

Comment: why don't you look at the html/css of the site you've screencapped? it'll show you how they did it.

Comment: I happened to see in the screenshot the site, there was no implementation code

Comment: Интересно, почему вы в русской части стека не задаете вопрос?

Comment: minus what? the same and you have no one to do so, it is an example

Comment: Andrey Fedorov  я задал вопрос , там ответа не поступило

Comment: @Geyan не видел. Вот на русском дока, может понятней будет. http://frontender.info/css-shapes/

Comment: Андрей - смотри http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549173/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Прогнозируемо в FF не работает - http://caniuse.com/#search=shape

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120541/discussion-between-geyan-and-andrey-fedorov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fake the outer shape of the text block by using floats with varying widths (each floated elements' height = text line height), which I'm sure could be automatically inserted via JS. If you can get the overall layout to work with this, it should be more cross-browser compatible than the shapes method used in the chosen answer (unfortunately). See the snippet below for the concept*:

*Just un-comment the border if you want to see what is actually happening

```css
.text-body {
  line-height: 1.25em; /* Must equal height in shape */
  text-align: justify;
}

.shape {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 1.25em; /* Must equal line-height in text-body */
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}
```

```html
<span aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="shape" style="width: 9em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 8em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 7em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 6em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 5em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 4em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 3em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 2em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 1em"></div>
</span>
<div class="text-body">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: And yet your answer is the best ! It is fully cross-browser

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working Snippet / [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/zayoze/1/edit?html,css,output) with a different shape, you can achieve same with other images too

```css
.element{
  shape-outside: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Triangle-grey.svg/2000px-Triangle-grey.svg.png);
  shape-image-threshold: 0.2;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>CSS shapes / dLotus</h2>
  <img class='element' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Triangle-grey.svg/2000px-Triangle-grey.svg.png" alt="">
  <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Read more here: [Working with Shapes | CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/working-with-shapes-in-web-design/)

Comment: Let me make a fiddle for you @Geyan

Comment: @Geyan I'm not sure if I understood your last comment, but check the link and let me know

Comment: I also showed a screenshot of an example, such a decision in your case, I have already seen and done myself, I did not get that option with a screenshot

Comment: It requires it as a screenshot, which was very similar Arpit Goyal

Comment: @Geyan Try the snippet, and if it's still not good for you, try to elaborate more on the problem

Comment: @AndreyFedorov same can be achieved with other ways, but if the image's space changes to something more weird or can be dynamic, this is the best possible to work at least known to me.

Comment: cool buddy! this is the top of the layout, will be my mentor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120540/discussion-between-arpit-goyal-and-geyan).

Comment: I unfortunately can not support the debate, I write through google translate

Comment: @AndreyFedorov the answer I was re-elected as the answer below still better and more convenient , automate add js what would it be for the end user more convenient